# How to keep onmouseover function until mousing over something else

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, onmouseover

I have just started to learn javascript. I wanted to know how to keep a function until you did another action. For example:

- Only finishing the onclick function when you click somewhere else out of the div.
- Keep onmouseover until you mouse over some other div or click outside the div.

I might not explain myself clearly, Im sorry about that. As I've said I'm just starting with JS. It might be easier, using jQuery but my objective here is to learn JavaScript syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks everyone that has helped, everything that was posted has allowed me to understand JavaScript better. Much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about a "javascript game loop" where one persists until another thing happens such as keydown then keyup.

Comment: U want to persist the effect of event? E.g. div changes color on mouseover - keep that color until another div is clicked?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter That is right. that is what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NLXmD/1/) doing what you asked.

This updates the view when an action is made. It is possible, instead, to update the view using `setInterval()` so that it's continuously checked, but that could cause slowdown.

HTML

```
<button id="start-exploding">Start Exploding</button>
<button id="stop-exploding">Stop Exploding</button>
<div id="start-fire">Mouseover to start a fire</div>
<button id="stop-fire">Put fire out</button>

<div id="explosions">Boom</div>
<div id="fire">I'm burning!</div>
```

JS

```
var explosions=false;
var fire=false;
function updateView(){
    var ex = document.getElementById('explosions');
    var fi = document.getElementById('fire');
    if (explosions) ex.style.display = 'block'
    else ex.style.display = 'none'
    if (fire) fi.style.display = 'block'
    else fi.style.display = 'none'
}

document.getElementById('start-exploding').addEventListener('click', function(){
    explosions = true;
    updateView();
});
document.getElementById('stop-exploding').addEventListener('click', function(){
    explosions = false;
    updateView();
});
document.getElementById('start-fire').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    fire = true;
    updateView();
});
document.getElementById('stop-fire').addEventListener('click', function(){
    fire = false;
    updateView();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not thinking about the events properly. The events always fire when they are supposed to be triggered. You dont want that to change or else youre going to start getting other problems. Instead of trying to change the way events are fired, you need to rethink your code design.

> Only finishing the onclick function when you click somewhere else out of the div.

Here you have code that you dont want called until you click somewhere. You should move this into an `onclick` handler for a different element, like `body`.

> Keep onmouseover until you mouse over some other div or click outside the div.

Same deal. Instead of trying to force `onmouseout` from happening, move the code from there into a `onmouseover` or `onclick` handler for another element.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a variable that updates in a mouseover event, but doesn't change back when the event stops, and then you can constantly check the state of the variable in an interval loop, e.g.

```
var id;
document.getElementByID("hoverMe1").mouseover(function(){
    id = "hoverMe1";
});
document.getElementByID("hoverMe2").mouseover(function(){
    id = "hoverMe2";
});
setInterval(function(){
    switch (id){
        case "hoverMe1":
            /*whatever your function is for hoverMe1*/
            break;
        case "hoverMe2":
            /*whatever your function is for hoverMe2*/
            break;
        default:
            /*nothing has been moused-over yet*/
            break;
    }
}, 1);
```

Basically, the variable gets set by the event-listener and then its state will constantly be checked every millisecond (so all effects will be pretty much instantaneous). This means that, once 'hoverMe1' has been moused-over it will persist to apply any changes you want, until 'hoverMe2' is moused-over, which completes the same purpose that blocking onmouseout would, which I don't think is possible.

Of course, you can do this for any event-listener, and as many elements as you want.

Answer (score 1):

To simple preserve the effect you don't need complicated timers or functions, you just need to know which event to handle. For example `mouseenter` event will fire only when mouse enters element - and whatever you do in the handler will persist even after mouse leaves.

Imagine you have 2 divs:

```
<div id="div1" >Div 1: Hover to change color to blue</div>
<div id="div2" >Div 2: Click to change Div1 color to Red </div>
```

you want to change color of DIV1 when mouse is over it. But you want to change it back only when you click the second DIV.

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");

div1.onmouseenter = function() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'Blue'
}

div2.onclick = function () {
    div1.style.backgroundColor = 'Red'
}
```

**Here's a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ygalanter/MSg8k/**